# Can't print struct

Tags: c, printing, struct

I'm trying to print the members of a struct called Task but it's only printing the first member and then it gives me a segmentation fault. Could somebody help me?

This is my code:

```
void listartarefas(Task *ff)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
   {
    if(ff[i].tipo == 1)
      { 
        printf("Agendada:\n");
        printf("%d\n",ff[i].identf);
        printf("%s\n",(ff[i].path));
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(ff[i].ano),(ff[i].mes),(ff[i].dia));
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(ff[i].hora),(ff[i].minuto),(ff[i].segundo));
       }
    else
       {
        printf("Executada:\n");
        printf("%d\n",ff[i].identf);
        printf("%s\n",(ff[i].path));
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(ff[i].ano),(ff[i].mes),(ff[i].dia));
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(ff[i].hora),(ff[i].minuto),(ff[i].segundo));
        }  
   }
}

int main()
{
 Task tf={2,1,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,20,00,1,5,22};
 Task tt={3,0,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,22,34,1,4,44};

 Task *ff[]={&tf,&tt};

 listartarefas(*ff);
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
listartarefas(*ff);
```

You are passing the indirection of *ff[], which is the first element of the array that you intend to pass. You might want to do this instead:

```
void listartarefas(Task **ff)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
   {
    if(ff[i]->tipo == 1)
      {
        printf("Agendada:\n");
        printf("%d\n",ff[i]->identf);
        printf("%s\n",(ff[i]->path));
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(ff[i]->ano),(ff[i]->mes),(ff[i]->dia));
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(ff[i]->hora),(ff[i]->minuto),(ff[i]->segundo));
       }
    else
       {
        printf("Executada:\n");
        printf("%d\n",ff[i]->identf);
        printf("%s\n",(ff[i]->path));
        printf("%d-%d-%d\n",(ff[i]->ano),(ff[i]->mes),(ff[i]->dia));
        printf("%d:%d:%d\n",(ff[i]->hora),(ff[i]->minuto),(ff[i]->segundo));
        }
   }
}

int main()
{
    Task tf={2,1,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,20,00,1,5,22};
    Task tt={3,0,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,22,34,1,4,44};

    Task *ff[]={&tf,&tt};

    listartarefas(ff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer really helped me but know I have a question: what if I want to pass "Task *ff" ? What do I have to change inside the function? Because if I don't change a thing it doesn't print what I want

Comment: Hello,

I am glad to hear the answer helped. Could you elaborate a little more please to make sure I understand the problem well?

Maybe you can post an example of how you want the call of the declaration of the function to be, and where you need to change the data.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're not passing a pointer to the array to `listartarefas` function. instead you dereference the array, which gives you the first element only, which is a pointer to a *single* structure, and you loop like it was two, leading to [*undefined behavior*}(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are a few weird things in your code, like you having an array of pointer, instead of simply an array of structures, which means you either have to change your function to accept an array of pointer or to change the array from an array of pointers to an array of structures.

My recommendation is to use a array of structures, and just pass it as is, because arrays naturally decays to pointers. So do e.g.

```
Task ff[] = {
    {2,1,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,20,00,1,5,22},
    {3,0,"home/fsm/mieti/projB/Makefile",17,22,34,1,4,44}
};

listartarefas(ff);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 listartarefas(*ff);
```

So this call is equivalent to

```
listartarefas(ff[0]);
```

Now what you are passing is the first element of the array `ff` which is the pointer to structure.
In the function you try to access `ff[1]` so you see a crash.

You can do something like what **@Joachim** as suggested